# Detect if a call has been answered and if not make another call to another number

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making an application that would be connected to a headset and when pressing the central button makes a call.
The problem would be that if that call is not answered I should redial another number but I've been looking and it is not possible to know if the other person answered the call or not, only if it has been made, just finished or there is no call in progress.
Is it possible to perform the action I need, right now I am using phoneStateListener.

Comment: It depends of sequences of States: IDLE-RINGING-IDLE means that the call was missed, IDLE-RINGING-OFFHOOK-IDLE means that it was answered, IDLE-RINGING-OFFHOOK-RINGING-OFFHOOK-IDLE means first call was answered then a second call was received/dialled (but there isnt any way, using PhoneState, to know if an answered was made for the 2nd one) and finally both calls were finished.

Comment: the problem is that this logic cannot be used for outgoing calls?, which is what I would need.

Comment: An outgoing call can be missed or answered. OFF-HOOK state is valid when a "voice connection" is established between two sides, so during incoming or outgoing call.